# Issues creating and iterating through Linked List?

Tags: c

When I run the program below, it prints "one: 1", instead of "one : 1, two: 2", as I had expected. Anyone know what's going on here? I am trying to create a function that will allow me to create as many linked lists as possible instead of just declaring global heads.

```
struct Node {
  int value;
  char label[10];
  node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;

int add(int data, char name[], node *head) {
  node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (newNode != NULL) {
    newNode->value = data;
    strcpy(newNode->label, name);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
}

node* createNewLinkedList(int d, char *name) {
  node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  newNode->value = d;
  strcpy(newNode->label, name);
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

int main() {
  node *head1 = createNewLinkedList(1, "one");
  add(2, "two", head1);
  iterate(head1);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `struct node`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to the node. Like all parameters in C, it is passed by value, therefore `head = newNode;` has no effect in the caller.

You need to change the signature to accept `node **head`, and add a level of indirection in order to make the changes in `add` be reflected in the `main`.

```
int add(int data, char name[], node **head) {
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->value = data;
        strcpy(newNode->label, name);
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need to pass `&head1` to the `add` method: `add(2, "two", &head1);`

P.S. Since you are adding {2,"two"} to the front of the list, your output will be  "two: 2, one : 1"

Answer (score 5):

`head = newNode;` will not do what you expect.

head is pass-by-value here.  Think about it.

Answer (score 2):

In `add`, you're not connecting the new node to the end of your list, you're merely creating a new node that's completely disconnected from your actual list. You also don't return an `int` from that function as per the function's signature.

I'm suspecting that you're wanting to set the new node as the head with this line:

```
head = newNode;
```

If that's the case, change `head` to type `node**` and do `*head = newNode`, otherwise you're just modifying a local variable to point to `newNode`, not the actual `head1` pointer being passed from `main`. In `main` you would then pass `&head1` to `add`.

**EDIT:** What would probably make more sense is to have `head->next = newNode;`, or to iterate to the end of the list and set the `next` value of the node which is pointing to `NULL` to `newNode`. ie.

```
node *lastNode = head;
while (lastNode->next != NULL) /* get to the last node in the list */
   lastNode = lastNode->next;

lastNode->next = newNode; /* add newNode to the end of the list */
```

Also have `newNode->next = NULL` instead of `newNode->next = head`. Now the output will be `"one : 1, two: 2"`, instead of `"two: 2, one : 1"` that would have happened if you added the `newNode` to the head.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your iterate `function` the problem is that `head1` is pointing to the last element on the list, not the first. You probably meant the the last line of the add function to be:

```
return head;
```

and 2nd line of your program to be:

```
head1 = add(2, "two", head1);
```

But that will still probably give you your output in the wrong order, because your `add` function is adding the new element to the start of the list, not the end.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem in detail, please go through `The C Programming Language` by `Kernighan & Ritchie` - Introduction (chapter 1.7/1.8) and Functions and Program Structure (chapter 4).

Hint: `pass-by-value` & `pass-by-address`

```
int main() {
    ...
    add(2, "two", &head1);
    ...
}
```

OTOH, you should validate the return address of `malloc` before de-referencing it (in `createNewLinkedList`).